github actions: windows-latest can not open gomp.lib
I have a c++&cmake project where I am using github actions to build and test on ubuntu 22.04 and windows latest platforms.
Unfortunately, the windows-latest linker fails with
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'gomp.lib'

while the ubuntu build is successful.
This is my yaml:
# This starter workflow is for a CMake project running on a single platform. There is a different starter workflow if you need cross-platform coverage.
# See: https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/main/ci/cmake-multi-platform.yml
name: CMake build and test on Windows

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

env:
  # Customize the CMake build type here (Release, Debug, RelWithDebInfo, etc.)
  BUILD_TYPE: Release

jobs:
  build:
    name: build and test
    # The CMake configure and build commands are platform agnostic and should work equally well on Windows or Mac.
    # You can convert this to a matrix build if you need cross-platform coverage.
    # See: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/learn-github-actions/managing-complex-workflows#using-a-build-matrix
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set reusable strings
        id: strings
        shell: bash
        run: |
          echo "build-output-dir=${{ github.workspace }}/build" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
          echo "bin-output-dir=${{ github.workspace }}/bin" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"

      - name: Configure CMake
        run: >
          cmake -B ${{ steps.strings.outputs.build-output-dir }} -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64
          -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${{ env.BUILD_TYPE }}
          -S ${{ github.workspace }}

      - name: Build
        run: cmake --build ${{ steps.strings.outputs.build-output-dir }} --config ${{ env.BUILD_TYPE }}

      - name: Test
        working-directory: ${{ steps.strings.outputs.build-output-dir }}
        run: ctest --verbose -C ${{ env.BUILD_TYPE }} -LE "^disabled$" -L WD

Would anybody know how to fix this?
EDIT
Added root CMakeLists (which is a bit messy to be honest):
# Works with 3.17 and tested through 3.29
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17...3.29)

# Set outputs directories.
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

# Project name and a few useful settings. Other commands can pick up the results
project(
        MyProject
        VERSION 0.1
        LANGUAGES CXX)

# Only do these if this is the main project, and not if it is included through add_subdirectory
if (CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME STREQUAL PROJECT_NAME)
    # Optionally set things like CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD, CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE here
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
    IF (WIN32)
        # set stuff for windows
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
    ELSE ()
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -Wextra -Wfloat-conversion -Wno-deprecated-copy -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -pedantic -O3 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -fopenmp${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
    ENDIF ()
    # Let's ensure -std=c++xx instead of -std=g++xx
    set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

    # Let's nicely support folders in IDEs
    set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)

    # Testing only available if this is the main app
    # Note this needs to be done in the main CMakeLists
    # since it calls enable_testing, which must be in the
    # main CMakeLists.
    include(CTest)
endif ()

# add dependencies
include(cmake/CPM.cmake)
CPMAddPackage("gh:nlohmann/json@3.11.3")
CPMAddPackage("gh:gabime/spdlog@1.13.0")
CPMAddPackage(
        GITLAB_REPOSITORY libeigen/eigen
        GIT_TAG 3.4
        OPTIONS "EIGEN_BUILD_DOC OFF"
        "EIGEN_BUILD_PKGCONFIG OF"
        "EIGEN_BUILD_DOC OFF"
)

include_directories(
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${FolderSource} # Find headers from source folder
        ${csv_SOURCE_DIR}/single_include # Issue #139 for this repo
)

# The compiled library code is here
add_subdirectory(src)

# The executable code is here
add_subdirectory(apps)

# Testing only available if this is the main app
# Emergency override MODERN_CMAKE_BUILD_TESTING provided as well
if ((CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME STREQUAL PROJECT_NAME OR MODERN_CMAKE_BUILD_TESTING)
        AND BUILD_TESTING)
    add_subdirectory(tests)
endif ()


And then each library I compile, has the following form:
# Optionally glob, but only for CMake 3.12 or later:
set(HEADER_LIST "${WingDesigner_SOURCE_DIR}/include/utils/logging_helper.hpp;${WingDesigner_SOURCE_DIR}/include/utils/path_helper.hpp;${WingDesigner_SOURCE_DIR}/include/utils/csv_helper.hpp")
# Make an automatic library - will be static or dynamic based on user setting
add_library(utils logging_helper.cpp path_helper.cpp csv_helper.cpp ${HEADER_LIST})
# We need this directory, and users of our library will need it too
target_include_directories(utils PUBLIC ../../include)
target_link_libraries(utils PRIVATE spdlog::spdlog Eigen3::Eigen csv gomp)
target_compile_features(utils PUBLIC cxx_std_17)

# IDEs should put the headers in a nice place
source_group(
        TREE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include"
        PREFIX "Header Files"
        FILES ${HEADER_LIST})


Is it working locally? Showing CMakeList.txt might help...

@Jarod42 I wish I knew -> I don't have a windows machine. I might have to make some virtual environment for that. I added my CMakeList

Is gomp required (with msvc)? It seems very gcc related. maybe just use OpenMP or nothing on windows.

@Jarod42 Are you saying the linking on the windows should be different, i.e. without the gomp?

Linking option might differ depending on platform. So you might try it. So remove or replace by OpenMP... Or see how to install gomp for msvc (if possible)...

@Jarod42, unfortunately, same issue: fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'OpenMP.lib'
